# Pagination Stops

Tags: posts, pagination, blog

I noticed pagination stops working after page 10 of blog posts.

When on page 10, and clicking the right arrow/next button button you are taken back to page 2 instead of page 11.

I have read several articles and posts about this issue, but feel like I can't get a solid answer to why this happens, and a solution.

Edited:
I have three "category" related templates - A category.php, category-blog.php, and category-news.php.
Reason for the three templates is to have different types of article pages - a Blog page and a News page (when creating an article I can use a tag to determine if the article will show up on the News or Blog page).

This code is on all the category.php template...

```
/* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /* Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
             * this in a child theme then include a file called called content-___.php
             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

        // Pagination
        if (function_exists("emm_paginate")) {
            emm_paginate();
        } ?>
```

This code is on the category-blog.php and category-news.php templates...

```
        // Pagination
        if (function_exists("emm_paginate")) {
            emm_paginate();
        } ?>
```

I looked in the functions.php file and there is no mention of "emm_paginate", or anything related to pagination.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you're working with? Are you replacing the default WordPress query with your own query to change what posts get loaded?

Comment: This is an issue I just discovered. I have not edited or replaced any code.

Comment: We can't see your code, so it's impossible for us to figure out the cause and solution. Please edit your question to include the code, even if you think it's not useful. Right now your Q is impossible to answer because there is nothing to work with. This is a QA site, rather than a discussion forum, I can't post an answer solving the question if there's little information :( I need to know how your pagination is built and how the page loads its content. Is this a theme you've bought in the past?

Comment: I edited the question to include the pagination code used on all three category templates, and a description on why we have three category templates.
I hope this helps with my pagination question. Please let me know if additional code is needed.